# Unable to debug tomcat server using eclipse

Tags: debugging, tomcat, configuration, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I'm using:

- Spring Tool Suite Version: 3.2.0.RELEASE
- Tomcat v7.0.42

When I just run my tomcat server everything is fine but I'm unable to debug it even locally. It produces following error:

```
Startich Apache Tomcat v7.0.42 at localhost has encoutered a problem. 

Server Apache Tomcat v7.0.42 bat localhost was unable to start within 45 seconds. If the server requires more time, try increasing the timeout in the server editor.
```

I've tried the following:

- increase the timeout.
- remove all the apps before starting the debugging.
- install new instance of tomcat (the only configuration that I've did on fresh install is turning on `Use Tomcat installation` and `Never publish automatically`).

But it didn't help, I still can only run the tomcat, without the debug option. Does anyone know how to make this debugging work?

Answer (score 0):

When I've used new, clear workspace for Spring Tool Suite, debugging started to work.
Cheers,